# bitmap отрисовывывается в большем размере

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmap, android-drawable

PNG квадратный со сторонами 720 x 720. При отрисовывании его в onDraw размер становится значительно больше, причем зависит от разрешения экрана. Если экран 800х480, то размер bitmap равен 1080 x 1080, если 2560x1440 - размер bitmap 2520 x 2520 (это видно глазом и через bitmap.getWidth() bitmap.getHeight())
При этом если размер измерять без загрузки bitmap (через BitmapFactory.Options) он соответствует исходному 720 x 720. У меня подозрение, что тут опять какая-то ерунда с dpi и px. Реальный размер bitmap на экране точно в пикселях, выходит что размеры PNG (720х720) в попугаях? На всякий случай код:

```
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.back);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0, paint);
```

Comment: Если смотреть в фотошопе, то размер картинки 720x720 указан в пикселях.Загадки во тьме, блин.

Comment: Вот что прочитал: "метод decodeResource учитывает density устройства и вытаскивает картинку из необходимой папки." Осталось понять как с этим бороться. Тем более что файл у меня только один и лежит в папке res\drawable.

Comment: Нашел у "соседей": "The image is scaled according to the dpi of the device you are using, you can put the resources in res/drawable-nodpi or res/drawable folder to get the correct size" Но у меня файл и так в папке res/drawable!

Answer (score 3):

В общем разобрался. Чтобы плотность пикселей не учитывалась и использовался реальный размер - нужно размещать файл в папке res/drawable-nodpi